# for loop prints the same thing in each iteration, should only print it once

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am having trouble in which my `for` loop prints the same vector 17 times from 17 elements instead of printing 1 time and drawing from 17 elements. What is going wrong?

Also, I am trying to add the mean value at the end of the inverted vector but it is saying that the dimensions are off. (Second function works but I included it for reference as it is inside ProcessSpike).

```
function [] = ProcessSpike(dataset,element,cluster)
%UNTITLED2 Summary of this function goes here
% Detailed explanation goes here
result = []
for a = 1:element
    for b = 1:cluster
        result = [result AvSpike(dataset, a, b)];
        mean = nanmean(result)
        r = [result]'
        r(end+1) = num2str(mean)
    end
end


function [result] = AvSpike(dataset,element,cluster)
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
% Detailed explanation goes here
Trans1 = dataset.Trans1;
Before_Trans1 = Trans1-600;
Firing_Time1 = dataset(cluster).time(dataset(cluster).time>Before_Trans1(element)&dataset(cluster).time<Trans1(element));
ISI1 = diff(Firing_Time1);
result = numel(ISI1)/600
result(result == 0) = NaN
end
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], i.e. define all input variables

Comment: What do you want to print inside your for loop?

Comment: I want to print a list of average firing rates for a given cluster for 17 different elements. So it should be on r and mean as below, but instead I get the same thing 17 times.

Comment: result =

   NaN


mean =

    1.7186


r =

       NaN
       NaN
       NaN
       NaN
    0.0050
       NaN
       NaN
    2.3067
       NaN
       NaN
       NaN
       NaN
       NaN
       NaN
       NaN
       NaN
       NaN
    0.1300
       NaN
       NaN
    0.4967
    0.0350
       NaN
   10.8767
       NaN
 (abbreviated due to limited character space)

Comment: You can make edits to your question instead of using abbreviated and unformatted code in comments!

Answer (score 0):

The prints are caused by lines that are missing an ending `;`, your editor should draw an orange line under these lines (warnings).
Regarding the mismatching dimensions, you are attempting to add a string (char array) to an existing array (`r(end+1) = num2str(mean)`). If the length of that char array does not match the length of the other elements in `r`, this will cause such an error. I would advise to not use `num2str()` here and just push a single value instead of the string representation of the value.

Answer (score 0):

I have added comments to a revised version of your code which hopefully make things clearer.

```
result = [] 
for a = 1:element
    for b = 1:cluster
        % Concatenate vertically (use ;) so no need to transpose later
        result = [result; AvSpike(dataset, a, b)];
        % Use a semi-colon at the end of line to supress outputs from command window
        % Changed variable name, don't call a variable the same as an in-built function
        mymean = nanmean(result); 
        % r = result'  % This line removed as no need since we concatenated vertically 
        % Again, using the semi-colon to supress output, not sure why num2str was used
        r(end+1) = mymean; 
    end
end
disp(r) % Deliberately output the result!
```